# Excel qty IN/qty OUT formula

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, inventory

I need help with a formula calculating qty in and out based on need date where oldest date pulls first if the PN matches an item on the inventory list.

I have a master list of total on-hand inventory.

| PN | Total QTY on-Hand |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 10 |
| bbb | 15 |
| ccc | 0 |

I need to compare the total on-hand inventory list with individual order lines, but I cannot figure out how to get the remaining balance to be the starting balance (QTY OH column) of the next line. Below is what I would like it to look like.

| Date Due | PN | QTY OH | QTY Demand | QTY Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/15/2023 | aaa | 10 | 2 | 8 |
| 1/17/2023 | aaa | 8 | 3 | 5 |
| 1/20/2023 | aaa | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 1/19/2023 | bbb | 15 | 11 | 4 |
| 1/25/2023 | bbb | 4 | 6 | -2 |
| 1/30/2023 | bbb | -2 | 3 | -5 |
| 1/11/2023 | ccc | 0 | 8 | -8 |
| 1/16/2023 | ccc | -8 | 7 | -15 |
| 1/21/2023 | ccc | -15 | 4 | -19 |

I have tried helper columns with vLookup (can't get away from circular references) and multiple IF/AND/OR statements. I can do SumProduct and SumIf, but I need to know the qty by the individual demand, not just the total. Is this something I can do with a formula or I need to move to VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract the sum of the qty demand(SUMIFS) to that point from the original qty on hand.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,H:I,2,0)-SUMIFS($D$1:D1,$B$1:B1,B2)
```

Note what is and what is not absolute referencing.  As the formula is dragged down it will only refer to the values above.

[image]

And, as you can see, since we are using conditional formula it does not matter that it is sorted by date instead of by PN and Date:

[image]

Comment: @Jenn2483 please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer/